# Apache Felix Webconsole 404

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi, apache-felix, bndtools

I am running BND tools in eclipse Kepler under windows 7 using JavaSE 1.6, and I am trying to start an Apache Felix framework 4.4.0 with a webconsole. I am quite puzzled since the same approach did seem to work under Ubuntu 14.04. What am I not seeing?

Besides the normal bundles, I am running the bundles for the Jetty webserver and the felix webconsole bundle. Now when I try to access `http://localhost:8080/system/console` I get a 404 from jetty. Now this does tell me that jetty is working correctly, but the webconsole somehow does not work correctly.

I have tried to re-add the bundles, restart eclipse, restart my PC, but all without effect. A minimal example does run on another machine running Ubuntu, and I used to be able to run it in the past as well.

Now I did find that there is a property "manager.root" by which I can set the location of the webconsole myself, but I haven't changed it (even if I did, it seemed ineffective). Is there a command to get the location from the console?

I am running only the following 4 bundles:

- org.apache.felix.gogo.shell
- org.apache.felix.gogo.command
- org.apache.felix.http.jetty
- org.apache.felix.webconsole

Active bundles:

```
ID|State      |Level|Name
 0|Active     |    0|System Bundle (4.4.0)
 1|Active     |    1|Java Servlet API (3.0.1)
 2|Active     |    1|Apache Felix Gogo Command (0.12.0)
 3|Active     |    1|Apache Felix Gogo Runtime (0.10.0)
 4|Active     |    1|Apache Felix Gogo Shell (0.10.0)
 5|Active     |    1|Apache Felix Http Jetty (2.2.2)
 6|Active     |    1|Apache Felix Web Management Console (All In One) (4.2.2.all)
 7|Active     |    1|osgi.enterprise (4.2.0.201003190513)
 8|Active     |    1|osgi.residential (4.3.0.201111022239)
```

Comment: Check that the Jetty bundle is publishing an HttpService, and that it is being consumed by the WebConsole bundle: `inspect cap service 5`

Comment: It seems that the service is published, but not used by the webconsole. It doesn't show up as being used by any bundle.

Comment: I suspect an incompatibility of the javax.servlet import. I note that you have the Servlet 3.0 bundle, and I think the Felix Jetty bundle exports Servlet 2.5. If WebConsole imports javax.servlet 3.0 then it will be incompatible with the 2.5 export from Felix Jetty. You can verify this by doing `inspect req osgi.wiring.package 6`. Please post the full output here, or in a gist.

Comment: Alternatively you could give https://github.com/evandor/skysail-webconsole a try, it should start up without any problems (at least that is the idea ;) - it is still in early alpha).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Neil, you were right. In the example on Ubuntu, I found that indeed I was using another version of the Java Servlet API (2.5). After making sure I was using version 2.5 on the windows machine as well, it all seemed to work fine.

The requirements of the webconsole package are as follows:

```
g! inspect req osgi.wiring.package 6
org.apache.felix.webconsole [6] requires:
-----------------------------------------
osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=javax.servlet)(version>=2.4.0)) resolved by:
   osgi.wiring.package; javax.servlet 3.0.0 from javax.servlet-api [1]
osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=javax.servlet.http)(version>=2.4.0)) resolved by:
   osgi.wiring.package; javax.servlet.http 3.0.0 from javax.servlet-api [1]
osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.osgi.framework)(version>=1.4.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) resolved by:
   osgi.wiring.package; org.osgi.framework 1.7.0 from org.apache.felix.framework [0]
osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.osgi.service.http)(version>=1.2.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) resolved by:
   osgi.wiring.package; org.osgi.service.http 1.2.1 from osgi.residential [8]
osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.osgi.service.packageadmin)(version>=1.2.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) resolved by:
   osgi.wiring.package; org.osgi.service.packageadmin 1.2.0 from org.apache.felix.framework [0]
osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.osgi.service.startlevel)(version>=1.1.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) resolved by:
   osgi.wiring.package; org.osgi.service.startlevel 1.1.0 from org.apache.felix.framework [0]
osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.felix.bundlerepository)(version>=2.0.0)(!(version>=3.0.0))) [UNRESOLVED]
osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.osgi.service.obr)(version>=1.0.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) [UNRESOLVED]
osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.osgi.service.cm)(version>=1.2.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) resolved by:
   osgi.wiring.package; org.osgi.service.cm 1.4.0 from osgi.residential [8]
osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.osgi.service.condpermadmin)(version>=1.0.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) [UNRESOLVED]
osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.osgi.service.log)(version>=1.3.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) [UNRESOLVED]
osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.osgi.service.metatype)(version>=1.1.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) [UNRESOLVED]
osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.osgi.service.permissionadmin)(version>=1.2.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) [UNRESOLVED]
osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.osgi.service.prefs)(version>=1.1.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) [UNRESOLVED]
osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.osgi.service.wireadmin)(version>=1.0.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) [UNRESOLVED]
```